# OpenGL on Mac OSX Mojave 10.14

Tags: python, macos, opengl, pyopengl, macos-mojave

On my latest MacOS Mojave (10.14) laptop, using Python3.6 I'm trying to use OpenGL (using pyOpenGL), and I'm getting an error when trying to use some of the functions. e.g.

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *

glGenVertexArrays(1)
```

`glGenVertexArrays` throws the following exception:

```
OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError: Attempt to call an undefined function glGenVertexArrays, check for bool(glGenVertexArrays) before calling
```

Under the hood, inside that function, there's a function called "baseplatform.py:checkExtension()" that receives "false" for trying to check the OpenGL extension: 'GL_ARB_vertex_array_object'

This code works perfectly on a windows machine.

some OpenGL functionality exists (some OpenGL functions are called before and don't raise errors). 
Anyone knows of a workaround? Maybe something to install\upgrade\downgrade?

I'm aware that Apple announced that they will drop support for OpenGL in the future, but from I could find, it's not supposed to affect 10.14 yet.

Comment: Have you tried on another macOS machine with a different version? Are you sure that feature's supported in Apple's OpenGL implementation?

Answer (score 1):

The function which you are using **is** available on macOS 10.14. macOS supports OpenGL up to version 4.1. For me it seems as if you forgot to initialise OpenGL context before using OpenGL functions.

Comment: How do I add the extension to the context?

This is what I'm doing today:

`glfw.window_hint(glfw.VISIBLE, False)
        window = glfw.create_window(self.cube_width, self.cube_width, "hidden window", None, None)
        assert window
        glfw.make_context_current(window)`

Comment: This function should not be a part of extension. You should be able to use it right away after creating a context. If you are not able to do it then it means that problem is caused by something else.